# How to make all files accessible in a single Google Drive folder?

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client

I am trying to access media files in a folder that is created by my webapp using the official google api library for node.js (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/).

On successful oauth, I create a folder `MyAppFolder`, and a `media` folder inside it.

The idea is that users will fill this `media` folder with whatever photos and videos they want, then my webapp will take them and display them on a page for the user to get an aggregate view of their media. I am able to get all the media files within the `media` folder. Here is my snippet of code:

```
async function getGoogleDriveMedia({ user, credentials }) {
  // await prepareDrive({ user, credentials });
  const rootFolder = await getRootFolder({ user, credentials });

  if (!rootFolder) {
    return;
  }

  const client = await createOauthClient({ user, credentials });
  const drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: client,
  });
  const mediaFolderRes = await drive.files.list({
    q: `mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='media' and '${
      rootFolder.id
    }' in parents`,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents)',
  });

  const mediaFolder = _.get(mediaFolderRes, 'data.files[0]');
  if (!mediaFolder) {
    return;
  }

  const mediaRes = await drive.files.list({
    q: `'${
      mediaFolder.id
    }' in parents and (mimeType contains 'image/' or mimeType contains 'video/')`,
    fields:
      'nextPageToken, files(' +
      [
        'id',
        'name',
        'webContentLink',
        'webViewLink',
      ].join(', ') +
      ')',
  });

  return _.get(mediaRes, 'data.files');
}
```

The problem now is that I'm not able to display these media because they are not publicly accessible. Is it possible to make the `MyAppFolder` and everything within it accessible to the public with a single permissions update? Or do I need to do it per file?

I also did a check on the `fields.files` parameter on their API explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/drive.files.list/m/drive/v3/drive.files.list

There isn't something like a `.previewLink` or some other image URL field.

How can I show these images on my webapp?

Comment: which Drive scope(s) are you currently using?

Comment: Using each file's `thumbnailLink` to obtain the tile image is not sufficient? Since you have read-only access to the files you should be able to obtain these for the authenticated user, and if the user clicks one you can fetch the full resolution image, etc.

Comment: I have to ask for full drive scope now. The issue here is that I do not fetch the file when I give a list of media to preview on the UI, because I will quckly use up the storage space on my server and risk traffic costs. I do a `drive.files.list` and then return either thumbnail link or link to the file. Both of which cannot be placed into an `<img />` element successfully unless they have read-only permissions set. Even if the user was logged into their google account, this will still not load because of different domains, the IAM check on google wouldn't know my UI has an authenticated user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to make the MyAppFolder and everything within it accessible to the public with a single permissions update? Or do I need to do it per file?

No there is no way to update everything in a file at once.  You are going to have to update each file.  Even updating the folder will not change the settings for the files with in the folder.

Just have your application change the permissions on the file after its uploaded.  In the mean time run though all the existing files and change their permissions.

Note: I hope you have informed your users that their files will be made public.

Comment: Yeah this is something I didn't want to do as it requires me to ask for write permissions when I only really need read-only permissions. I guess it's something I have to make very clear and be careful about touching people's files.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `file.thumbnailLink`. It may have enough resolution for your purposes and it's public. NB imho, the fact that it's public is a security bug which might get fixed at some point in the future.

NB there is a bug in your code. You are fetching `nextPageToken` correctly, but then you aren't using it to test if there are more pages in the files list that you need to fetch.

Comment: Is it public only when  the folder is public or Are all images in Google drive public?

Comment: from my testing, the thumbnails appear to be public regardless of permission

Comment: Oh Wow. Seems like a big privacy overlook.

Comment: Interesting, I'll check the sizes for those and see if they're good enough, then I can ask for readonly permissions.